# Prestashop 1.6 - free shipping based on final total price

Tags: prestashop, price

I am using Prestashop 1.6. My site is offering "free shipping" for purchases **over 80 bucks**. My site is also having a promotion of "Buy 1 get 1 free".

Now, one item can cost about **60 bucks** and I insisted the customer to buy 2 products from the same category in order to be entitled for buy 1 get 1.

If a customer buys one product, it should cost 60 bucks (no free shipping because final price < 80)

If a customer buys 2 = 120 bucks but after the "buy 1 get 1 free" promotion, the final total price is 60. So by right, this customer is not getting free shipping but my site gives free shipping to this customer because the "free shipping" logic is based on the total price before discounted (120 bucks).

How do I resolve this? I want the free shipping calculation to be based on the final total price (after discounted)

[image: click here to view print screen]

Comment: Can you be more clear how this question has to do with programming? I don't see any code related things in this question

Comment: If this can be solved without digging the code, I would like to know how. 
If i must dig the code, i would like to know which file to modify and how.

Comment: I feel like your question would be better suited for the PrestaShop forums

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to override method `getPackageShippingCost()` from `Cart.php`.

And change those lines:

```php
    } else {
        if ($shipping_method == Carrier::SHIPPING_METHOD_WEIGHT) {
            $shipping_cost += $carrier->getDeliveryPriceByWeight($this->getTotalWeight($product_list), $id_zone);
        } else { // by price
            $shipping_cost += $carrier->getDeliveryPriceByPrice($order_total, $id_zone, (int)$this->id_currency);
        }
    }
} else {
    if ($shipping_method == Carrier::SHIPPING_METHOD_WEIGHT) {
        $shipping_cost += $carrier->getDeliveryPriceByWeight($this->getTotalWeight($product_list), $id_zone);
    } else {
        $shipping_cost += $carrier->getDeliveryPriceByPrice($order_total, $id_zone, (int)$this->id_currency);
    }
}
```

by replacing `$order_total` to `$orderTotalwithDiscounts`:

```php
    } else {
        if ($shipping_method == Carrier::SHIPPING_METHOD_WEIGHT) {
            $shipping_cost += $carrier->getDeliveryPriceByWeight($this->getTotalWeight($product_list), $id_zone);
        } else { // by price
            $shipping_cost += $carrier->getDeliveryPriceByPrice($orderTotalwithDiscounts, $id_zone, (int)$this->id_currency);
        }
    }
} else {
    if ($shipping_method == Carrier::SHIPPING_METHOD_WEIGHT) {
        $shipping_cost += $carrier->getDeliveryPriceByWeight($this->getTotalWeight($product_list), $id_zone);
    } else {
        $shipping_cost += $carrier->getDeliveryPriceByPrice($orderTotalwithDiscounts, $id_zone, (int)$this->id_currency);
    }
}
```

If you don't know how to override a class, please have a look at [this documentation](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Overriding+default+behaviors).